# Create an objects with input value

Tags: javascript, frontend

I have the various number of input like that. I do not control the exact numbers of inputs as they are coming from backend

```
<input value="User">
<input value="email@mail.com">
<input value="Adress">
```

My task is to grab all values from inputs and put them into object. Object is look like that

```
contactDetails = {username, mail, adress}
```

So no matter how many inputs I have 3 input values assigning to object keys and if there another 3 inputs they go to separate object with the same key values so in the end it should look like that

```
   {
        "username": "User",
        "mail": "email@mail.com",
        "adress": "Adress",
    },
    {
        "username": "User 2",
        "mail": "email@mail.com 2",
        "adress": "Adress 2",
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below.
Each group of three inputs will have two classes for each element. One being `i` followed by a number (CSS does not allow classes to start with numbers). The other class is either `user`, `email`, or `address`.

The `getValues` function, then looks at how many `user` elements there are which will tell you how many groups as there will always be all three elements for all the groups.

It then uses this number to loop through the `for` loop pushing the three values into a `data` array.

```js
let data = []

function getValues() {
  const num = document.querySelectorAll(".user").length
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    data.push({
                 "username": document.querySelector(`.i${i}.user`).value,
                 "email": document.querySelector(`.i${i}.email`).value,
                 "address": document.querySelector(`.i${i}.address`).value,
              })
          
  }
  console.log(data)
}

getValues()
```

```html
<input class="i1 user" value="User1">
<input class="i1 email" value="email1@mail.com">
<input class="i1 address" value="Address 1">

<input class="i2 user" value="User2">
<input class="i2 email" value="email2@mail.com">
<input class="i2 address" value="Address 2">

<input class="i3 user" value="User3">
<input class="i3 email" value="email3@mail.com">
<input class="i3 address" value="Address 3">
```